# Is there any metadata API available for Salesforce Wave Analytics?

Tags: metadata-api, einstein-analytics

Since Salesforce Wave Analytics objects are highly customizable, do we have metadata APIs available to retrieve information dynamically? I am aware of the fact that static metadata is available for wave objects but i am searching for dynamic metadata API.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `/services/data/v39.0/wave/` to retrieve all the metadata objects available[image]

You can drill into each of these to get detailed APIs and metadata .

Comment: Ya i am aware of this..but i am looking for a way to get dynamic metadata for an object

Comment: Looking for same please suggest.